# Make custom ipv6 packets in java

Tags: java, ipv6

I'm working on mobile ipv6 in java and want to make custom ipv6 packets.

how do I write class to make ipv6 packets and I put the payload myself?

Following is the example of the similar class:

```
CustomIPv6 ipv6 = new CustomIPv6();
ipv6.setSource("::1");
ipv6.setDestination("::1");
ipv6.setPayload(MyArrayOfByte); //The byte array which I made it myself. -> the mobile ipv6 extention
ipv6.setUpperLayerType(CustomIPv6.MobilityHeader);
ipv6.sendPacket();
byte[] recv = ipv6.ReceivPacket();
//Now is the time for process the received packet and send some kind of ack.
```

Thanks all friends in advance.

Comment: The question is that I want a class similar to CustomIPv6. I just put CustomIPv6 class above to show what I need. Any way thanks for attention. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with http://jnetpcap.com/  however it requires libpcap or winpcap be installed.  This facility is useful for network hacking which could be why it is not better supported. ;)

Comment: Good point. I think with Java 7 you can use setcap to enable privileges on linux.